# How to click element with overflow:hidden in cucumber / capybara

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, smartgwt

i am trying to test smart GWT application. I Have one critical problem. I can't click element using:

```
find(:xpath, "/html/body/div[10]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/table/tbody[2]/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/img").click
```

it's returns

> Unable to find xpath
>   "/html/body/div[10]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/table/tbody[2]/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/img"
>   (Capybara::ElementNotFound)

Here is the code:

```
<td id="isc_UV" class="comboBoxItemPickerCell" style="font-size:22px;">
<span id="isc_UW" handlenativeevents="false" $9a="picker" $89="isc_SelectItem_17" tabindex="-1" style="margin-left:0px;-moz-user-focus:ignore;cursor:pointer" role="button">
<img id="isc_UX" class="comboBoxItemPicker" align="TEXTTOP" width="18" height="22" border="0" draggable="true" suppress="TRUE" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; display: block;" src="a.gif">
</span>
</td>
```

and there are many div tags over this img with overflow:hidden. How to click these elements ?

Comment: Rather than the overly long and brittle xpath selector could you try find(:css, '#isc_UX').click

Answer (score 1):

try passing `visible: false` option to `find` method call